# Skia debug info and Img_en error

Tags: android, runtime-error

I'm starting to do an Android app and recently it gives me a strange error. Sometimes it gives me the error below on Img_En and I don't know what it is about.

> ```
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Open!data_format:3
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Run!width:522,height:12
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): calc_hist_yuv: use 0.088000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): saturation:10
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): calc_map_yuv: use 0.346000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): do_mapping_yuv: use 0.059000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Run: use 2.541000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.867: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Close!
> 03-19 17:59:36.887: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Open!data_format:3
> 03-19 17:59:36.887: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Run!width:522,height:135
> 03-19 17:59:36.887: E/Img_En(26017): calc_hist_yuv: use 0.961000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.887: E/Img_En(26017): saturation:40
> 03-19 17:59:36.887: E/Img_En(26017): calc_map_yuv: use 0.408000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.887: E/Img_En(26017): do_mapping_yuv: use 0.815000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.897: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Run: use 9.712000 ms!
> 03-19 17:59:36.897: E/Img_En(26017): ImgEn_Close!
> ```

And sometimes, the code gives me a debug info like the following:

> 03-19 17:59:36.897: D/skia(26017): don't do enhance for small image...

I think, according to some research that I have done, that these two things are related, but I don't see how to solve them.

Comment: What language or other tools are you using to make your app? This doesn't look like Java which is one of the most common ways to do so.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and Java.

Comment: I don't see anything in what you have posted that can help us diagnose the problem. Can you describe what you do that causes the error?

Comment: I think that I don't do anything that can causes the error. I just made 2 interfaces, one with fields to make a login and another with a list view.

Comment: Looks more like debug output than an error. Is there actually something not working?

Comment: No, everything is working like a charm, so I don't see why it's giving me this error. This seems awkward to me.

Comment: Developers sometimes leave debug messages enabled to help tracking bugs or forget to disable them. They also don't say that something is wrong, all I can see are some performance measurements and log about what happens. I would simply ignore the messages as long as they don't affect you.

Comment: I just asking if anyone has an idea about what can it be because it can cause me problems in the future. But as zapl said it probably is debug messages that are enabled since it don't affect my program at all.